# How Can I Make Sure My Home Server Stays Up As Long As There's Power?

Tags: windows, bios, port-forwarding, power-management, wake-on-lan

I'm working on setting up a Minecraft server for me and some friends alongside some other software, so I'm turning my old HP computer into it (still running Windows 10 for now). I've noticed one thing, where after my power goes out, the computer doesn't turn back on automatically, which is expected, but I need to figure out how to make it turn on regularly. [HP has a help article on it](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04040117), but I think it will only work at the time specified, which I can't live with. I've heard about Wake Up On LAN, but I'm unsure about how to access it remotely (aka off my home network). I'm fine with port forwarding, as it's necessary for most of the services I'm going to be running. I just need a way to make sure my "server" can stay up all the time, as long as there's power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a timer, BIOS should have some kind of 'auto-boot after power cut' option. I've no idea if this still exists on modern EFI boot structures, but all my PCs are set to this in BIOS…

> Inside the BIOS menu, look under the “Advanced” or “ACPI” or “Power Management Setup” menus for a setting named “Restore on AC/Power Loss” or “AC Power Recovery” or “After Power Loss.”

This is different per manufacturer, so you may have to hunt around for it.

To complement this, you will need the Windows user to [auto-login](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/automatically-log-in-to-your-windows-10-pc/) to the required account, otherwise it will sit at the login screen until you do it manually.

Quote from [TechNewsWorld - How to Set Up Your Computer to Auto-Restart After a Power Outage](https://www.technewsworld.com/story/how-to-set-up-your-computer-to-auto-restart-after-a-power-outage-86034.html)

Comment: This.  However, if you live in an area where the power goes up and down a lot, you could have data loss.  If you really want to keep it up and safe, get a UPS.

Comment: @Keltari indeed. It’s not something I ever really think about. We get power cuts here about once a decade;)

Comment: "This. However, if you live in an area where the power goes up and down a lot, you could have data loss. If you really want to keep it up and safe, get a UPS." And a generator to take over, because that UPS will be drained in a very short space of time.